# Prove that a polygon with perimeter $2a$ can be covered by a circle with diameter $a$

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics

I've found a proof here [Polygon can be covered by circle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2086483/polygon-can-be-covered-by-circle) that the maximum distance between any two vertex of the polygon is less than $2a$.

But how to prove that actually all points are within that circle?

Comment: Found the proof here: https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=PNwlDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=Prove+that+a+polygon+with+perimeter+2a+can+be+covered+by+a+circle+with+diameter+a&source=bl&ots=wpgSthVMJa&sig=ACfU3U3NAugrlAOOu0I9wGaZFR52kSZPDA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd6b7Lrpb1AhUESuUKHXiqAxYQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=Prove%20that%20a%20polygon%20with%20perimeter%202a%20can%20be%20covered%20by%20a%20circle%20with%20diameter%20a&f=false

Answer (score -1):

Let the set of all circles of the plane be parametrized in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by the coordinates of their centre and their radius: $(x, y, r)$. The set of circles that cover a given open surface $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$: we can prove that its complementary is open by looking at a non-covering circle, which is characterized by intersecting with the convex hull of $U$ then seeing that we have wiggling room for the values of $(x, y, r)$. Thus there exists a minimum radius covering circle. This circle must intersect with the polygon in either of two ways (construct smaller covering circles if not true):

1. Two vertices form a diameter.
2. Three vertices form a triangle that is circumscribed by the circle such that the center of the circle is inside of the triangle.

In both cases, the perimeter should be at least twice as large as the diameter of the circle.

Comment: Diameter should be $a$, not $4a$.

Comment: You can't take the radius equal to $a$ because the problem requires the diameter to be $a$. Replacing then $a$ by $\frac a 2$ in your answer might invalidate your reasoning. Please reconsider your answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).